# ZFS pool has one drive mounted twice

Tags: zfs

My ZFS array is best summed up like this:

```
# zpool status
  pool: sbn
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 8K in 44h43m with 0 errors on Mon Feb 11 21:07:56 2019
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    sbn         ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdg     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdh     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdi     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdj     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdk     ONLINE       0     0     0
    spares
      sdk       FAULTED   corrupted data

errors: No known data errors
```

You will note that the drive **sdk** appears twice -- once as an active member of the RAID array and once as a spare.  This condition is persistent across reboots.

Does anyone have a suggestion of how best to fix this?   (I have two additional drives in the JBOD that are supposed to be the spares.)

Comment: This is Linux? Don't use the `/dev/sd*` devices to create your zpools. Use the corresponding `/dev/disk/by-id/*` device links instead. The `/dev/sd*` device names are not consistent between boots.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes well this was my first ZFS system that I put up and I followed the tutorials and all of them I could find use the drive letters not the ID numbers.  More than that I haven't found any way to convert the array from drive letters to ID have you?

Comment: Congrats, you found a bunch of bad tutorials then. As for converting, I'm not really sure. I've never had to fix one of these pools myself.

Comment: Proper zfs subsystem doesn't rely on device names but rather on their signatures. Recent versions of ZOL too. Thus relocating devices inside the tree should do no harm. I did this in 0.7.11 at least- changinng device names doesn't affect the pool.

Comment: You may want to import the pool next time with `zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id sbn` to have the `by-id` listing with `zpool status`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zpool remove` only applies to inactive hotspares (which this weird extra sdk is) and cache or log devices, so I'd just `zpool remove sbn sdk` and see what happens.

If that refuses to work, you may need to `zpool offline sbn sdk` (to get rid of the active, non-faulted sdk vdev in the main pool) first. If things get *super* weird, you may need to export the pool and re-import it (preferably using /dev/disk/by-id, not bare devicenames!) first.

Comment: If I do the offline command as you suggest, does that mean that when I add the drive back in it will have to be rebuilt?    Is there any downside to that?  The zpool remove does nothing.

Comment: I have similar issue on FreeBSD 12.2. I have 2 pools `zroot` and `zdata`. Suddenly appeared new pool with name `zroot` with map to vdev from `zdata`. I don't understand how it is possible. If I'll make `zpool remove` using id of strange pool, will my data on `zdata` be kept? Currently I can boot from stick and import `zdata` and `zroot` pools without any errors. All hardware are worked without errors.